# Angular 2 build in prod not work in safari

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, safari, production

My site using angular 2 works in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari. I have the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL: http://.../api/
>
> Unhandled Promise rejection:
>      ";Zone:"
>      "angular"
>      "; Task;"
>      "Promise.then"
>      "; Value:"

In my request to `/api/`, I have a token in the header. I don't know the problem came from angular or my API server (nginx 1.11.9).

For building, I used:

```
ng build --prod
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you the code where the error is happening?

Comment: If you check the developer console, is your code sending the required header?

Comment: @LeonRadley, yes the authorization header has been sent

Comment: Then it's your backend server that is the problem. debug why it's sending a 401

Comment: @LeonRadley thanks for your answer. The problem is, it doesn't send back a 401 when i use Chrome or Firefox. And it works even for safari if i remove the "--prod". Do you have any idea why it didn't work in the case of "prod" ?

Comment: I would start by testing that your backend works as expected using a tool such as postman www.getpostman.com. The problem you are seeing above is because you don't have a .catch(error => ...) on the request. Maybe angular teats it differently in prod mode.